# how to using FindAll to get List in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi Everyone sorry i have a question, i have a simple code to get cheaper books from a list, i use one class book with properties, one class to set the books to the list and one main program. here is the book class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AdvanceCSHarpLambda
{
   public class Book
   {
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public int Price { get; set; }

   }
}
```

and here the BookRepository class (List)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AdvanceCSHarpLambda
{
    public class BookRepository
    {
        public List<Book> GetBooks()
        {
            return new List<Book>
            {
                new Book() {Title="T1", Price=1 },
                new Book() {Title="T2", Price=2 },
                new Book() {Title="T3", Price=3 }
            };
        }

       
    }
}
```

and here the main program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AdvanceCSHarpLambda
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var books = new BookRepository();

            var cheapBooks = books.FindAll(bookCheaper);

            foreach (var book in cheapBooks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(book.Title);
            }
        }

        static bool bookCheaper(Book book)
        {
            return book.Price < 10;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is i got red line in *books.FindAll(bookCheaper)*, any one can help me whats going on in this redline? thx before

Comment: BooksRepositor has no such method ... you forgot to use its method to get the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `GetBooks`

```
books.GetBooks().FindAll(bookCheaper)
```

Comment: the problem has been solved with this solution thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

Your books should be a List, not BookRepository.

Answer (score -1):

You need a Predicate for the FindAll function.

```
books.FindAll(x=>x.Price < 3)
```

Something like this.

Comment: OP did in fact pass a predicate in form of `bookCheaper`.